# What is a sort key guaranteed to come at the end of a list of unicode strings?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I need to sort some dictionary keys so that the u"/" character is at the end. When using non-unicode strings I did this with a function:

```
>>> L = ["/", "C", "b", "A"]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda item: item.lower() if item != "/" else tuple())
['A', 'b', 'C', '/']
```

This uses (abuses?) the fact that tuples are sorted after strings in python. But unicode strings are sorted after tuples, so this won't work if the keys are unicode. So, for example,

```
>>> L = [u"/", u"C", u"b", u"A"]
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda item: item.lower() if item != u"/" else tuple())
[u'/', u'A', u'b', u'C']
```

- What kind of objects are sorted after the unicode type?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Those aren't `unicode`s.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: The OP doesn't say they are..

Comment: @Martijn: Sure, but the first non-ASCII character to come around will make the code implode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to mix types or have a special sort key: just use a tuple as the key in all cases:

```
sorted(L, key=lambda item: (item == "/", item.lower()))
```

That means "/" is keyed as `(True, "/")` while all other strings are `(False, "...whatever...")`

Comment: That's a much better way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Return a unicode character that is guaranteed to be sorted last: [`sys.maxunicode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode):

```
sorted(L, key=lambda item: item.lower() if item != u"/" else sys.maxunicode)
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: uhm, great idea! :-P